# Forgot how to boot linux when one CPU is dead

Tags: linux, cpu

A computer has one CPU dead, and I found a while ago a solution to boot it using the other CPU by adding a simple flag in the `linux` line configured by GRUB. Without this option, the OS ubuntu 14.04 would simply not boot (and I can't upgrade as newest kernels do not support a required proprietary NVIDIA driver), and recent linux does boot but with an error:

```
smpboot: do_boot_cpu failed(-1) to wakeup CPU#1
```

However, for some reasons I needed to reinstall Grub, and this removed this flag and I can't remember its name anymore. Any idea what flag I need?

Comment: [Here you have a list of available commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html). Maybe you can recall from reading it.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity this is a kernel option, not grub. But I found it, it's `nosmp`!

Comment: Oh, okay, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved by adding `nosmp` in the `linux` line of grub!

Comment: That's fine if you only have 2 cores, and the 2nd one is dead. All that does is limit you to the very first one. If you have more than 2 cores, then you are needlessly restricting your processor.

Comment: @Bib I have only 2 cores in my case. That said, if you know a more configurable way to enable/disable processors, please let me know.